# Count() returning 1 with comma separated string with explode

Tags: php, count, explode

I have a field that stores tags comma seperated. I'm trying to count the number of items listed.

Let's say I've already pulled the data from the DB, and the $tags variable has the following info:

```
$tags = "Videos,Magazines,Store";

// First separate tags by commas, put into into array
$tagArray = explode(",",$tags);

// Count how many items are in the array
$arrayCount = count($tagArray);
```

That always returns "1", regardless if there's an item in the array or not. the $tags variable can have any number of items - from empty, to a single item like "Videos" to multiple items "Videos,Games,Store" etc.

Can someone help me out on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Returns `3` [for me](http://codepad.org/jHkGFYYW). Are you [accidentally calling](http://codepad.org/GQnFA0NX) `count()` on the original string?

Comment: Not reproducible. Please post your actual code. (Maybe avoid mixed-case variable names.)

Comment: Encoding issue? Are your commas not commas?

Comment: The exact code you gave us is correct http://codepad.org/GnU9hoxI

Comment: Thanks. You guys were right, it wasn't a problem with this code, just how I was using it later.

Answer (score 3):

From PHP manual:

If delimiter contains a value that is not contained in string and a negative limit is used, then an empty array will be returned, **otherwise an array containing string will be returned.**

**So, simply - if delimiter is not found in string, explode do nothing.** If Your variable contains empty string, count() will return 1. **You need NULL value for count() to return 0.**

Try this:

```
    $tags = "Videos,Magazines,Store";

    // First separate tags by commas, put into into array

    $tagArray = ($tags != '')?explode(",",$tags):NULL;

    // Count how many items are in the array

    $arrayCount = count($tagArray);
```

Comment: Count on NULL generate a warning. Use array() instead

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, it returns 3 as expected, because you have provided **right input** string to work the code, but problem arise when you **assign database field's value** to `$tags`, because it can also contains **empty string** as you have said in your question.

so as you have told it can be zero or more than zero tags in db field, so when `$tags` contains no tags or empty string then as php [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function's manual says:

> If delimiter contains a value that is not contained in string then **array containing string like [ " " ]** will be returned.

So when your `$tags` contain **empty string** then `explode()` returns **array containing empty string**, so now your `$tagArray=[""]`, after exploding you are using `count()` function, so as per [php manual of count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) It

> Returns the number of elements in array_or_countable. **When the parameter is neither an array nor an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned**. There is one exception, if array_or_countable **is NULL, 0 will be returned**.

so because your `$tagArray` is **not NULL but `$tagArray=[""]`, so `count($tagArray)` is returning one.**

So for solving it use the code below:

```
$tags = "Videos,Magazines,Store";
// it can also contains empty string like $tags = ""
$arrayCount = ($tags)?count(explode(",",$tags)):0;
//here $arrayCount will have 3 as expected, But if your $tags contains empty string it will return 0 instead of 1.
```